# Android CustomListView OnClick

Tags: java, android

Hello Everyone Iam was Making a AndroidStudio List view app and I noticed custom list view is much better so I decided to switch into custom !

I have problem with the onclick listener of my CustomListView I cant get the position of clicked item so I cant gather info from that

> Because :

**This is My Listview OnClick ListenerCode (From internet)**

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {
            // here the position element of this method will give you the row number on which the click happened.
            //Then you can get individual values like name[position], address[position] and then pass these values through an intent
        }
    });
```

**It Dosent Work And Gives a Error on OnItemClickListener() !**
Saying :

```
 Error:(118, 37) error: incompatible types: <anonymous android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
Error:(120, 37) error: cannot find symbol class AdapterView
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I used ALT+ENTER to fix The Error it Creates a

```
AdapterViewCompat.
```

Behind the OnItemListClickListener() and Suggest to implent methods so I Do ALT+ENTER and it will be like :

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {
            // here the position element of this method will give you the row number on which the click happened.
            //Then you can get individual values like name[position], address[position] and then pass these values through an intent
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
```

it Gives Error on first OnItemClick Funtion I though its a Duplicate of second one so I delete that but when I do it give error on second one too !
Saying :

```
   Error:(119, 37) error: incompatible types: <anonymous android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

SO the code from internet dosent work

> Question : OnClickListener For CustomListView maybe?

Comment: Try with code which you picked from internet. If you are looking to get data then position can help you.

Comment: the code dosent work ! I said I used the code and I have problems with that

Comment: what problem you had with that snippet of code

Comment: Are you using `recylcerview` and you imported this `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in your code ?

Comment: **check your imports, android.widget.adapterView or android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat**. *Use either android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat ( in case of backeard compatibility - if your application targets API less than 15) or android.widget.adapterView*. if you give the full java file - it is easier to inspect your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView's `setOnItemClickListener` listener takes `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` as param and you're trying to set this `android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener` there and hence the error.

Change it to right listener type and the error should be resolved.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                     //implement methods
})
```